# How do I configure an ant build to include a shared library in my Android project?

Tags: android, ant

My project references a shared library. I state this in my manifest file, as follows:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.myapp.mysharedlib"/>
```

In my .classpath file I references the location of the lib:

In eclipse, I adapt my build path to suit, and I do not export the file. However, running the following fails:

```
ant debug
```

The build breaks on my references to mysharedlib.

My question is, how do I compile using ant, without incorporating the shared library into my project (i.e. copying it to libs)?

Comment: "I state this in my manifest file, as follows" -- `<uses-library>` is only for shared libraries that are part of your custom ROM. Is that indeed what you are trying to do?

Comment: Maybe `android update project -p projectDirectory -l pathToLibrary` might help you?

Comment: CommonsWare - correct, that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: hwrdprkns - I have run android update lib-project -p ./ on my current project to generate the build.xml and associated files

Comment: I would presume that you need to develop an SDK add-on that matches your shared library, then compile with that SDK add-on. For example, when you build against Maps V1, you use `<uses-library>` to tie in your library, but there is a compile-time equivalent of `com.google.android.maps` added via an SDK add-on. The contents of that add-on's JAR are not included in the APK, but the library itself then supplies those classes. I presume that the mechanics of creating such an add-on are covered on the AOSP site.